# ASP.NET MVC : Remove Empty fields in Details View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Suppose I have the following:

Action:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    Person person = personRepository.GetPerson(id);

    return View(person)
}
```

This is my view:

```
    Name: <%= Html.Encode(Model.Name) %><br />
    Age: <%= Html.Encode(Model.Age) %><br />
    Birth Date: <%= Html.Encode(Model.Birthday) %><br />
    Country: <%= Html.Encode(Model.Country) %><br />
    Weight: <%= Html.Encode(Model.Weight) %><br />
    Height: <%= Html.Encode(Model.Height) %><br />
    Phone: <%= Html.Encode(Model.PhoneNumber) %>
```

My issues is that country, weight, and height are nullable. How can I do something like this

```
foreach (var field in Model)
        if (var field != null)
        {
             field.name + ": " + field.value
        }
```

I can do it like this but i'm sure there is a better way:

```
  if (Model.Name != null){
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Name)%>
       }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: My solution to this problem was to ensure that nullable fields in my database weren't null but instead contained empty strings.  I'm sure this breaks all kinds of rules though.  Hopefully we can get a good answer here.

Comment: I'd go for Nullable<DataType> for Country, Weight and Height in View Model so that entity does not change. I would also consider using Html.EditorFor and Html.LabelFor helper methods.

Comment: @WorldsIsRound thanks went with the helper method, seems to do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Country:<%: string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Country) ? String.Empty : Model.Country  %>                
<br />
```

note that **:** In <%: %> MVC 2 you can use it for Html.Encode

Comment: +1 Now is there anyway to get that to happen automagically when using Http.EditorFor or Http.TextFor, etc?

Comment: @Pete Not built in you could make your own extension method to wrap those and check for null.